# Visual Studio private accessors and checking in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, reflection, shadowing

I've generated unit tests on a private method using Visual Studio's own "Create Unit Tests..." option.

Great, it works, but if I try to check my code in now I break the build because VS has created a private accessor class in AppData/Local/Temp that is required to build. If I try to put this file in my source tree, it won't compile as the compiler says it "must define a body". Really don't understand this reflection lark...

This is the accessor class:

```
#region Assembly AgentConfiguration_Accessor.exe, v4.0.30319
// C:\Projects\AgentConfigurationTests\obj\Debug\AgentConfiguration_Accessor.exe
#endregion

using Agent.ConfigurationData;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace Agent.AgentConfiguration
{
    [Shadowing("Agent.AgentConfiguration.AgentConfigurationGui")]
    public class AgentConfigurationGui_Accessor : BaseShadow
    {
        protected static PrivateType m_privateType;

        [Shadowing(".ctor@0")]
        public AgentConfigurationGui_Accessor();
        public AgentConfigurationGui_Accessor(PrivateObject value);

        [Shadowing("_agentPaths")]
        public AgentPaths _agentPaths { get; }
        [Shadowing("_agentServiceName")]
        public static string _agentServiceName { get; set; }
        [Shadowing("UpdateStatus@1")]
        public void UpdateStatus(string statusMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using the Private Accessors for some time, I had some troubles in getting the code to compile after some branching and merging with our Souce Code Versioning system.

I started researching on the topic and found an article in the [Visual Studio Team Test](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/) blog. As far as I have understood it, you should **not** use the Private Accessor classes any more.

There is a blog article in the [Generation of Private Accessors (Publicize) and Code Generation for Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2010/01/18/publicize-and-code-generation-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx) that states that this feature **is not further supported any more**:

> We have stopped working on these features for Visual Studio 2010 and
>   may remove them from the product in following releases.  This is due
>   to the following reasons:
>
> - Lack of resources and time: The focus for this release has been to improve the experience for manual testers, so the priority for the
>     code generation and publicize features has been lowered.  There have
>     also been other issues with the publicize functionality that we
>     utilize that have not been addressed.
> - New features by Language teams:  As the language teams have made modifications to their project types and languages, we have been
>     unable to respond to the changes they have made and have not been able
>     to work with the new features they have introduced.

Of course there are are suggestions about what you could do instead:

> For those who wish to continue testing internal APIs, you have three
>   options:
>
> 1. Use the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.PrivateObject class to assist in accessing internal and private APIs in your code. 
>      This is found in the
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll assembly.
> 2. Create a reflection framework that would be able to reflect off your code to access internal or private APIs.
> 3. If the code you are trying to access is internal, you may be able to access your APIs using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute so your test
>      code can have access to the internal APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use this feature, though I did use it for a short while when I first started learning about unit tests.  In general, unit tests should test the public surface of the class.  If you start from that principle, there should be no need for the accessor classes.

But how do you test important private logic in your classes?  I generally extract private methods into helper classes, where they become public methods (think "single responsibility principle").  As public methods, of course, they become testable without the accessor class.  The original class then gets a private instance of the helper class.

In addition to letting you avoid the accessor classes in your tests, this approach makes it easier to use mock objects in your testing.  When you're testing the original class, instead of giving it the "real" helper class, you give it a mock instance.  This decouples the test for the original class from the logic in the helper class: if you introduce a bug in the helper class, the helper class's tests fail, but the tests for the original class are unaffected.

Comment: Yeah I did get a funny feeling from testing a private method. I've now used a mock to wrap the method in question and done it that way. Still, would be nice to know how to do it (and maintain portability of the project) in VS.